# Family counting problem: A valid approach?

Tags: combinatorics

> The Smith family has 4 sons and 3 daughters. In how many ways can they be seated in a row of 7 chairs such that at least 2 boys are next to each other?

**My approach:** 
Since I need 2 boys to be together, I fix their position and vary the rest of the children. There are 2 remaining boys. So basically

choices for 7 chairs 1*1*2*1*3*2*1

Why is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have counted the number of ways to put

- Albert in the first seat
- Bob in the second seat
- Charlie and David in the two next seats
- The three girls in the final three seats

This is clearly not all valid ways to place the children.

I suggest you look into the number of ways that *fail* the given criterion instead. In other words, the number of ways to place the children so that no boy is next to another boy. That happens to be a *lot* easier to get right. Then subtract that from the number of ways to arrange them at all, and you have your answer.